# Error property _id using Typescript in ANGULAR

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, undefined

I have this message Error in angular:

```
src/app/components/employee/employee.component.html:67:92 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

67 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mr-2 (click)="deleteEmployee(employee._id)">
                                                                                              

  src/app/components/employee/employee.component.ts:8:16
    8   templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
```

Error occurs in the template of component `EmployeeComponent`

[image]

Model : `Employee`

[image]

Service :

[image]

JavaScript Function:

[image]

Please a need know why this happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the value being passed in for `_id` is "uninitialized" and therefore its value is undefined. I can't tell without seeing more of your code. One way to fix this would be when you instantiate the employee, make sure `_id` is actually being set to a value, otherwise set it to `''` (blank string) and check that it has a value or not in your delete().

Another option would be to edit your delete function

```
deleteEmployee(_id: string | undefined){
     if(_id) { //Checks if the passed variable has a value
          ...
     } 
     else {
          // Error
     }
}
```

Comment: I managed to solve the error declaring it in my service object as empty, but your answer also works, thank you very much!